# ImportError: Couldn't import Django ... Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I know there are several questions/answers about this, but I can;t figure out what I should do. 
I wanted to get started with Django and installed it with `pip install` and added Python37 and Python37-32 to my environmental variables, and I guess it worked, because I can run several Python commands in my shell. 
But every time I try to

```
    python manage.py runserver
```

it gives me an error.

I also set up my virtual environment and activated it, but I think there's a problem with Django. But because I installed it with `pip install django` I know it's there and I can use commands like `django-admin startapp` ... So I guess Django is working. I don't really know what PYTHONPATH means and where to find it. It would be pretty nice if anybody could take a look at my error.

Here you can see that Django is installed : 
    #

```
**C:\Users\Kampet\Desktop\Python-Django\mysite>pip install django Requirement already satisfied: django in c:\users\kampet\appdata\local\programs\ python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (2.2.4) Requirement already satisfied: pytz in c:\users\kampet\appdata\local\programs\py thon\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from django) (2019.2) Requirement already satisfied: sqlparse in c:\users\kampet\appdata\local\program s\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from django) (0.3.0)**

# And thats my error
**C:\Users\Kampet\Desktop\Python-Django\mysite>python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in main
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 16, in main
    ) from exc
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available o
n your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual env
ironment?**
###################
```

Here is where my virtual environment is located.

Python-Django

-----------------mysite

-------------------------main

-------------------------mysite

-------------------------manage.py

-----------------venv

-------------------------Include

-------------------------Lib

-------------------------Scripts

-------------------------pyvenv.cfg

This is my manage.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
import os
import sys


def main():
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

#

I don't know why it can't find the module "django" / django.core.management
I also can't find django.core.management anywhere in my files, but I reinstalled and upgraded django several times. I don't know if this helps you.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: There is a `source` command you need to use, I know on cPanel you can find the exact command in Setup Python App. Try `source venv` ?

Comment: Please, try to activate venv by this command `.\venv\Scripts\activate` and then install Django again.

Comment: @ArtemKolontay Yeah you're right. I forgot to install Django on my Virtual Environment, but this unfortunately didnt fix the problem for me yet. I am looking forward to understand/find out what JonPizza said.

Comment: @JonPizza Okay thank you for the advice! I will take a look at it and try to find out what you mean :)

Comment: JonPizza meant the same thing, but for *nix systems. I provided you with Windows equivalent.

Comment: @ArtemKolontay Okayy.. I activated my venv and im into it and installed Django on it.
(venv) C:\Users\Kampet\Desktop\Python-Django>
 
OH MAN TY... I just figured out that I had to start the server while I am in the venv!!! 
I always started that venv and opened another shell to run the server.. I really appreciate it!

Comment: Cool. I posted this as an answer then. Please mark it as a solution.

Comment: Yeah sorry didn't know you were on windows. Good Artem was here to help!

Comment: @JonPizza you couldnt know :) Should have said it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On the Windows machine, you should activate `venv` by this command `.\venv\Scripts\activate` (please note, you should be in the folder where this venv is)

Then inside activated venv install Django `pip install django` and in the same terminal run the server `python manage.py runserver`

Answer (score 5):

I had similar issue in my windows 10 system and solved using pipenv. Steps with commands given below.

1. cd/Go to the project folder
2. Setup the virtual environment `pipenv install`
3. Activate the virtual environment `pipenv shell`
4. Install django `pip3 install django`
5. Run the project `pipenv run python manage.py runserver`

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue with:

- django installed globally
- virtual environment setup and activated
- django project setup under venv activated

When trying to run the project, it could not import django anyway.

Adding path to manage.py in variables did not help but as mentioned above, installation of django under venv activated actually resolved the issue.

Your case may be different but try this scenario:

1. Setup venv
2. Activate venv
3. Install django
4. Create django proj
5. Try to run django proj

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when you install pip packages as a normal user other than root user. `pip install <package name> --user` command actually creates a directory called as `.local` in the users home directory under which the packages are installed.

Fix:

1. Find the django package installed location `sudo find / -name 'django'`
2. Copy the path from find command output.
3. Create export variable in ~/.bashrc file with PYTHONPATH variable.
4. Save the file and exit.
5. Exit from the normal user prompt.
6. Login again as the normal user.
7. Run the command `env` to check the PYTHONPATH variable set in the output.
8. Run the command `python manage.py runserver <ip address: port>`

Comment: Exactly what i'm looking for. I stop exec manage.py with sudo and that work =) thx

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are working on the command prompt.

Use this command '

> `workon your_env_name`

'

Answer (score 0):

try running it in anaconda prompt instead of cmd, that worked for me

Comment: Why? `Anaconda` installs other packages.

Comment: I think what you mean to say is: check what python environment you are using to run it. You don't need to install Anaconda.

Answer (score 0):

Install Python3, Make sure its on PATH, make sure PIP is installed, Install virtualenv with PIP, setup virtualenv, activate virtualenv, install django.

Or you can  try to run the command `pipenv shell` before start the server with py manage.py runserver in vscode terminal.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I reinstalled python to a global folder on the C drive and by mistake wrote PYTHONPATH With:\Python and not C:\Python\Scripts in global variables, but in local variables it was written correctly

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtlIi.png)
On Windows, you should activate env by this command .\env\Scripts\activate (please note, you should be in the folder where this env is)

Then inside activated env install Django: `pip install django` and in the same terminal run the server: `python manage.py runserver`

Comment: To make it accessible for the search engine and to be future proof it would be great if you include the text as text and not as an image. Thank you :)